# Unable to make a PyEZ connection: ConnectUnknownHostError

Tags: ansible, vagrant, junos-automation, pyez

I am trying to use **juniper_junos_facts** from the Ansible Junos module to query some VM's that I provisioned using Vagrant. However I am getting the following error.

```
fatal: [r1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to make a PyEZ connection: ConnectUnknownHostError(r1)"}
fatal: [r2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to make a PyEZ connection: ConnectUnknownHostError(r2)"}
```

I see in the following document [Here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-ansible/topics/task/troubleshooting/junos-ansible-connection-errors-troubleshooting.html) on juniper.net that this error occurs when you don't have the host defined correctly in the inventory file. I don't believe this to be an issue with my inventory file because when I run **ansible-inventory --host**  all appears to be in order

```
~/vagrant-projects/junos$ ansible-inventory --host r1
{
    "ansible_ssh_host": "127.0.0.1", 
    "ansible_ssh_port": 2222, 
    "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": ".vagrant/machines/r1/virtualbox/private_key", 
    "ansible_ssh_user": "root"
}
~/vagrant-projects/junos$ ansible-inventory --host r2
{
    "ansible_ssh_host": "127.0.0.1", 
    "ansible_ssh_port": 2200, 
    "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": ".vagrant/machines/r2/virtualbox/private_key", 
    "ansible_ssh_user": "root"
}
```

My playbook is copied from the following document which I got from [Here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-ansible/topics/reference/general/junos-ansible-modules-overview.html) on juniper.net.

My Inventory File

```ini
[vsrx]
r1 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/r1/virtualbox/private_key
r2 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/r2/virtualbox/private_key

[vsrx:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
```

My Playbook

```yaml
---
- name: show version
  hosts: vsrx
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: retrieve facts
      juniper_junos_facts:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        savedir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    - name: print version
      debug:
        var: junos.version
```

Comment: ConnectUnknownHostError(r1) means r1 is sent as host and not the IP to PyEZ. You need to pass ansible_ssh_host as host. I think if you don't pass any, we take them as default.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, can I ask how you pass ansible_ssh_host as host to PyEZ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using `connection: local` you need to give the module full connection details (usually packaged in a provider dictionary at the play level to reduce repetition):

```yaml
- name: retrieve facts
  juniper_junos_facts:
    host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
    port: "{{ ansible_ssh_port }}"
    user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    passwd: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
    ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}" 
    savedir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
```

Full docs are here (watch out for the correct role version in the URL): https://junos-ansible-modules.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/juniper_junos_facts.html where you can also see what the defaults are.

To fully explain the "provider" method, your playbook should look something like this:

```yaml
---
- name: show version
  hosts: vsrx
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    connection_info:
        host: "{{ ansible_ssh_host }}"
        port: "{{ ansible_ssh_port }}"
        user: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
        passwd: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
        ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}" 

  tasks:
    - name: retrieve facts
      juniper_junos_facts:
        provider: "{{ connection_info }}"
        savedir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    - name: print version
      debug:
        var: junos.version
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much cmsirbu. I did have to add 1 line to the conncetion_info to point to my ssh_key that I was using which was ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}"

Answer (score 0):

This answer for people who will find this question by error message.

If you use connection plugin different from `local`, it can, and usually caused by this [bug](https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib/issues/378) related to variables ordering

Bug already fixed in Release 2.2.1 and later, try to update module from Galaxy.